# What are the easy steps for ServiceNow on-premise installation?

Tags: servicenow

Can someone share easy steps to install Snow on-premise?
Also, from where I can get the bits? Is it free for limited test?

Comment: Is not possible anymore. Just for few old clients. SN is always in the cloud now.